# Is there a way to overwrite local files in Google Chrome with service worker running?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

Just found that if you have a service worker in your app and you use local overwrite in Chrome dev tools, the view shows a new file but it executes the old file, so you can't use the debugger properly. But anyway it doesn't work at all the file is not updated.

My service worker is only to allow using files in memory (from indexedDB) and the rest of the files just use fetch in Worker (no cache).

I was also trying to use extension resource overwrite but it also doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to change the file locally without modifying an app where the service worker is running?

I'm not sure If I should report this to the Chrome Dev tools team, since this is like a bug or missing an important feature.Just found that if you have a service worker in your app and you use local overwrite in Chrome dev tools, the view shows a new file but it executes the old file, so you can't use the debugger properly. But anyway it doesn't work at all the file is not updated.

My service worker is only to allow using files in memory (from indexedDB) and the rest of the files just use fetch in Worker (no cache).

I was also trying to use extension resource overwrite but it also doesn't work.

**Does anyone know how to change the file locally without modifying an app where the service worker is running?**

I'm not sure If I should report this to the Chrome Dev tools team, since this is like a bug or missing an important feature.

Comment: For reference reported it to Google Chromium project https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1340258